# Drop rows with datetime condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 14 columns and with more than 1000 rows.

I am trying to drop rows that have value before 1/1/2015 from column DATE. First, I manipulated the columns DATE by doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import date

df['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime('DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Then, trying to drop rows with this script:

```
df.drop( df[ df['DATE'] < pd.Timestamp(date(2015,1,1)) ].index, inplace=True)
```

But it returns:

```
KeyError: 'DATE'
```

Comment: did you define df dataframe first?

Comment: did you try `df1 = df[(df['DATE'] >= pd.Timestamp(2015,1,1)]`

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually works, but the `pd.to_datetime` has a small typo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2], 'DATE': ['2002-11-7', '2020-7-27']})

df['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)

df.drop( df[ df['DATE'] < pd.Timestamp(date(2015,1,1)) ].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing date in the argument of Timestamp works for me.

Try this:

```py
df.drop( df[ df['DATE'] < pd.Timestamp(2015,1,1) ].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with my first line of code to manipulate the date. Could not print the data after that line. And removing date still receive same error